# getElementById returns NaN

Tags: javascript, nan, getelementbyid

Consider the following example snippet of my code. I have tried parseInt with no luck. Here, I want javascript to set a number in a cell `PICweight` then retrieve it later and place it in a different cell `totalcabin`. You can see here, I want to set the number as 1, but when the code runs, it returns `NaN` in `totalcabin`.

```
<td id="PICweight" type="tel"></td>
<script>
    window.onchange = function setfields() {

        document.getElementById("PICweight").innerHTML = 1;
        var PICweight = document.getElementById("PICweight").value;

        var totalcabin = document.getElementById("totalcabin");
        totalcabin.innerHTML = +PICweight
    }
</script>
```

Comment: td's don't have values.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no value property of `td` elements. When you use `.value` on normal html elements (non input elements) you end up with `undefined`. Later, you use `+` to implicitly cast `undefined` to a number, which results in `NaN` and your subsequent observation.

You should be using `.textContent` instead of value to get the text inside of the td element.

```
var PICweight = document.getElementById("PICweight").textContent;
```

Comment: That makes sense, Thanks!